# Check Bios uefi firmware files with md5sum

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bios, uefi

Can I get md5 hash for UEFI, BIOS firmware files with md5sum due to the new LoJax malware ( https://thehackernews.com/2018/09/uefi-rootkit-malware.html ). If yes, how to?

Comment: You are not vulnerable to LoJax if you use Secure Boot, Windows and the majority of Linux distributions, support Secure Boot.  Getting an MD5 hash of your firmware will not prevent this malware.

Comment: Thank you, @Ramhound, for the tip, i know that, I have read the article, but I want, and perhaps not only I will want, to know a tampering of the firmware files and decide what to do further. Not to do a secure boot everytime then not infected anyway.

Comment: A OEM should provide the md5 hash of a file, you just have to calculate the hash of the file, knowing the md5 hash of the firmware that has been applied will not prevent this malware.

Comment: Just get md5 checksum hash, and if hashes are different, decide what to do further. @Ramhound

Comment: If malware is installed, then md5 hashes of the firmware files will be different, right? @Ramhound

Comment: You are only going to know the MD5 of the file, an OEM won't provide the MD5 of the firmware once it's applied, so knowing the current firmware's MD5 hash won't indicate if you are infected.  Enable Secure Boot, leave it enabled, and you won't have to worry about the malware.

Comment: I still need the answer. It is actual for the new personal computers. Everybody liable for security must to know these md5 hashes.

Comment: If you want to know the md5 of the current firmware, that isn't possible, it also will not prevent this malware.

Comment: Thank You, @Ramhound, for your trying to help. I have understood that hashing will not prevent the malware. But If the malware makes changes to the firmware files why I can not make only md5 hashes?